# How can I get the unix group name based on the group id?

Tags: unix, user-accounts

How can I get the unix group name based on the group id?

Note: looking in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/groups` is not a solution as some systems may be using NIS so the users and groups are not listed there.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The libc function for this is [getgrgid()](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=getgrgid).

To use it from the shell, try this command:

```
getent group GID | cut -d: -f1
```